# Jenkins reports "Failed to rotate log, looks to have already been deleted"

Tags: jenkins

My build server was full. I `rm`-deleted some old builds from Jenkins' jobs directory.

Then I found out about a [code snippet which can be run from Jenkins' Script Console](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/VXO-6ZvCxC0/OMoIY-tuRCoJ).

But running this code snippet now causes the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: example.com/builds/25 looks to have already been deleted; siblings: [lastFailedBuild, 24, lastStableBuild, 88, lastUnsuccessfulBuild, 90, lastSuccessfulBuild, 89, legacyIds, lastUnstableBuild]
```

To my observation, the "cleanup" is now stuck, as running the code snippet repeatedly shows `example.com/builds/25 looks to have already been deleted`, and directories that should get cleaned up according to my *Discard Old Builds* strategy don't get so.

Comment: Well, did you manually `rm` that old build?

Comment: @Martin, yes, I manually `rm` that old build.

Comment: Well then, no wonder `job.logRotate()` says `build looks to have already been deleted`, because it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by

1. creating the missing directory with Jenkins' permissions (e.g `mkdir ${JENKINS_DIR}/jobs/example.com/builds/25 && chown jenkins:jenkins ${JENKINS_DIR}/jobs/example.com/builds/25`)
2. running the code snippet repeatedly until all error messages were gone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem trying to run Groovy Script to reset my build number. For the offending build I used the new .dropLinks() method to clear out that build.

```
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("your-build-name")
//THIS WILL REMOVE ALL BUILD HISTORY
item.builds.each() { build ->
  try {
    println "Deleting build " + build.number
    build.delete()
    // After clearing out all the builds using delete
    // Try another run using dropLinks() to clear out some orphaned stuff
    // build.dropLinks()
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    println "Unable to delete build"
    println e.message
  }
}
item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)
```